# hide outline on phonegap android

Tags: css, cordova

I am testing phonegap android to do something, and I want to hide the outline on link and input tag.

```
outline:0;
```

is useless.

How can I hide it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For links and input tag

```
 a, input
        {
        outline:0;
        border:none;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);   
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```